# WPF & WinForm SerialPort control difference thru RS232?

Tags: wpf, winforms, serial-port, usb

I tested 2 almost same code with WPF and WinForm to communicate serial port thru USB and RS232 respectively. Both WPF and Winform works fine thru the USB port. but I was not able to receive the response from RS232 port with WPF whereas WinForm has no issue. Code attached. 
Is there any difference between WPF and Winform to communicate thru Seiralport thru RS232?

pmSerialPort thru USB
lsSerialPort thru RS232

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        DispatcherTimer dtTimer = new DispatcherTimer();  
        SerialPort lsSerialPort = new SerialPort();
        SerialPort pmSerialPort = new SerialPort();

        private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbPMPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
            cbModel.SelectedIndex = 0;
            pmSerialPort.PortName = "COM14";
            lsSerialPort.PortName = "COM2";
        }

        //Status check
        private void BtnStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pmSerialPort.Close();
            laserSerialPort.Close();

            try
            {
                ComboBoxItem cbItem = (ComboBoxItem)cbPMPort.SelectedItem;
                pmSerialPort.PortName = cbItem.Content.ToString();
                pmSerialPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message");
            }

            try
            {
                lsSerialPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message");
            }

            if (lsSerialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    stsLsPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    txtBlkLsPort.Text = "Laser COMPort is Open!";
                }
                else
                {
                    stsLaserPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    txtBlkLsPort.Text = "Laser COMPort is NOT Open!";
                }
                if (pmSerialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    stsPMPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    txtBlkPM.Text = "PM COMPort is Open!";
                }
                else
                {
                    stsPMPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    txtBlkPM.Text = "PM COMPort is NOT Open!";
                }

                string strStsLs;
                double stsLs;

                lsSerialPort.WriteLine("RD" + Environment.NewLine);
                lsSerialPort.WriteLine("{Enter}");

            txtLsStatus.Text = lsSerialPort.ReadExisting().Trim();

            if (lsPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    stsLsPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    txtBlkLsPort.Text = "Ls COMPort is Open!";
                }
                else
                {
                    stsLsPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    txtBlkLsPort.Text = "Ls COMPort is NOT Open!";
                }
                if (pmSerialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    stsPMPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    txtBlkPM.Text = "PM COMPort is Open!";
                }
                else
                {
                    stsPMPort.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    txtBlkPM.Text = "PM COMPort is NOT Open!";
                }

        }


        private async void BtnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



            if (pmSerialPort.IsOpen && lsSerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                pmSerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
                pmSerialPort.WriteLine("*CU");
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                lsSerialPort.WriteLine("WG0" + Environment.NewLine);
                txt1WG0.Text = lsSerialPort.ReadExisting();
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                MessageBox.Show("Please check connection", "Action Needed");
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                txt2BNCDC.Text = "P";
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
                lsSerialPort.WriteLine("WU1);
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                txt3WU1.Text = lsSerialPort.ReadExisting();
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                pb.Value = 2;
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                lsSerialPort.WriteLine("WU2");
                txt4WU2.Text = lsSerialPort.ReadExisting();
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                lsSerialPort.WriteLine("WU3");
                txt5WU3.Text = lsSerialPort.ReadExisting().Trim();
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                lsSerialPort.WriteLine("WU4");
                txt6WU4.Text = lsSerialPort.ReadExisting().Trim();
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                pb.Value = 4;
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000);
                pmSerialPort.WriteLine("*UV");
                txt9LPPower.Text = pmSerialPort.ReadExisting().Trim();
                pb.Value = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please click Check Status for details");
            }
```

Comment: With RS232 you mean a native old school serial port with a sub D9 connector? And by USB you mean a USB-to-RS232 adaptor also with a sub D9 connector at the other end? Are you sure the device you are connecting to works on RS232 levels and not on TTL 5 or 3.3V?

Comment: The RS232 is the sub D9 connector. for USB, the device is connected directly the PC via a USB cable(USB connectors at both end). The device was pretty old design, communicate and work on RS232

Comment: OK, and how are you joining the cable with both USB ends to the RS232 device. Maybe your device uses a non-standard pinout? Have you checked the configuration of the native serial port at BIOS level? Sometimes you have a menu to enable or change the electrical levels to other standards like RS485 or RS422.

Comment: @MarcosG. Thank for helping. Sorry that I think i didn't make my self clear. I connect my PC to 2 devices. Device A with USB cable(both end USB); device B with RS232 cable at both end. I dont have issue with device A with the code, the problem happened on device B. I tested to type the command manually thru Hyperterminal, I was able to get expected response from the hyperterminal. with the code I have, i was not able to get return from device B. I will look at configuration as you suggested.

Comment: Can you say what is device B (the one that fails)? And how exactly did you get it working with Hyperterminal? Is something different in the settings (baud rate, parity, flow control)?

Comment: @MarcosG. just realized that device B requires to have Enter as part of command while device A doesn't need. After /r was added at the end of command, i am able to get the expected response from device B now. Thank you very much anyway for help!